# Sound stops working in soundboard (Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, audio, avaudioplayer

In my soundboard app, after some time the sound will stop working until the app is closed and opened again. Can't figure out what is wrong! here is my code:

In the .h file :

```
(imported files here)

@interface MainView : UIView {

}
- (IBAction)pushButton2:(id)sender;

@end
```

In the .m file:

```
(imported files here)


@implementation MainView

- (IBAction)pushButton2:(id)sender {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound1" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

}

@end
```

Comment: It would help to see the delegate methods. Does the sound stop before the end of the mp3?

Comment: nope. the sounds will stop playing after a while.

Comment: Still, the delegate methods would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it would cause the behavior you're seeing, but you're definitely leaking the AVAudioPlayer each time the button is pressed.  Additionally, I would just load it once (say, in `viewDidLoad`), rather than on each button press.  Perhaps something like:

```
@interface MainView : UIView
{
    AVAudioPlayer* audioPlayer;
}
- (IBAction)pushButton2:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation MainView

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound1" ofType:@"mp3"];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;

}

- (void) viewDidUnload
{
    [audioPlayer release], audioPlayer = nil;
}

- (IBAction)pushButton2:(id)sender 
{
    [audioPlayer play];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you! What would it look like if I added another sound?

Comment: You could just have one AVAudioPlayer instance per sound.

Comment: I had trouble with getting all of my sounds to stop. I just made the all different audio players and in my stop action I made all of them stop. Worked for me!